# How do i stop loopbackjs from running i want port 3000 back?

Tags: loopbackjs

i built a cool app using loopbackjs, works great but I can't shut it down. How do I stop it on localhost:3000? commenting out the config.json won't kill it

```
{
   "restApiRoot": "/api",
   "host": "0.0.0.0",
   "port": 3000,
   "remoting": {
   "context": false,
   "rest": {
   "handleErrors": false,
   "normalizeHttpPath": false,
   "xml": false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+C on the command line from where you started the loopback app. That will kill the app and release the port it was using.